# How to integration a VBA with a board?

Tags: excel, vba, select, range, excel-2010

I need a code to intégrate some information in the empty line but the problem is when i use the code it put the line under the board and not in the board but under the empty line.

`derniere_ligne = Sheets("Montre").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select`

Comment: What is a "board" here?  Do you mean Table/ListObject?

Comment: yes sorry It table, I don't no the name in english.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Table/Listboject then you can use the `ListRows.Add` method:

```
Sub TestAddRow()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim rw As Range, selRow as Range
    
    Set selRow = Selection.Cells(1).EntireRow 'get the selected row

    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Montre").ListObjects(1)  'destinationTarget table/listobject
    Set rw = lo.ListRows.Add.Range     'add a row and get the range for the new row

    'populate the new row
    With rw
        'Copy individual cells from selected row
        .Cells(1).Value = selRow.Cells(1).value
        .Cells(2).Value = selRow.Cells(3).value
        'etc etc

        'or if all cells tp be copied are contiguous, you can use (eg)
        .Value = selRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 5).Value

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it's almost that ! Because I need to copy a spécifique selection (active ligne). And copy in table.

Comment: See updates above.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time, that's the good modification !!